# Is it possible to get the Artifact Name in Release?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a requirement to get the build artifact name in release? I dont see a predefined release variables which can get this. Is there a way to fetch this?

Answer (score 5):

If you mean you want to get the `Artifact Name` which is defined in `Publish Build Artifacts` task in Build process (By default it's `Drop`), then you can run below PowerShell script calling the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/artifacts/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to retrieve the value and set a variable with logging command. After that you can use the variable in subsequent tasks...

1. Enable [`Allow scripts to access the OAuth token`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=vsts#use-the-oauth-token-to-access-the-rest-api) in `Agent Phase`
2. Add a PowerShell task to run below script

   ```
   $url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/build/builds/$env:BUILD_BUILDID/artifacts?api-version=4.1"
   Write-Host "URL: $url"
   $pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
       Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
   }
   Write-Host "artifactName:" ($artifactName = $Pipeline.value.name)

   #Set Variable $artifactName
   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=artifactName]$artifactName"

   #Then you can use the variable $artifactName in the subsequent tasks...
   ```

[image]

Comment: Thank You Andy! This is exactly what i'm looking for. I will try this out and update. I wonder why the Drop Name is not exposed as environment variable.

Comment: I get artifactName: drop also but it is incorrect.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT I am also struggling with the same issue. I think the question is not the Drop folder but the name of the file(s) published inside it. Do you know how it is possible to get those values?

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a hack/kludge, but if you name your Release to be the same as the package you are releasing, you can get the name from the variable

```
$(Release.DefinitionName)
```

So if your build creates a package called My.Cool.Package in a build pipeline called my_cool_package, that ends up being aliased in the release pipeline as `_my_cool_package`.

Naming the Release pipeline the same as the package (My.Cool.Package) allows you to access the package and files within it (for doing XML and JSON transforms for example in other tasks) by using

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Release.PrimaryArtifactSourceAlias)/$(Release.DefinitionName)
```

Comment: Definitely too hacky... And it only works if the name is static. (no version number inside)

Answer (score -2):

This is [well-documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#default-variables) under the sections *General Artifact Variables* and *Primary Artifact Variables*.

The primary artifact name is `Build.DefinitionName`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already gone through the documentation.  Build.DefinitionName gives the Build Name. My question was to get the Artifact Name which gets created when we publish the artifacts in the  Build process.

Comment: @rsch006 Do you mean the `Artifact Name` which defined in `Publish Build Artifacts` task (By default it's `Drop`) ?